# Specify signature when using x:Bind

Tags: xaml, uwp, xbind

UWP allows you to bind to a static method. I'm trying to get a time string by using

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind MyDateTime.ToString(MyPatternString)} />
```

where `MyPatternString` is "h:mm tt".

The problem is that `DateTime`'s `ToString()` method has several different signatures. The first one receives an `IFormatProvider`. Because of this, I get a build error:

> Function parameter 'provider' is invalid or missmatched

Is there any way to tell it that I wish to use the signature which accepts a string? I'd have thought it would automatically know this.

Comment: Can't you just insert an IFormatProvider (like CultureInfo.Invariant or so)?  Otherwise, create your own conversionmethod to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a method to your ViewModel and use that instead!

That way your binding expression can be changed to this:

```js
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind FormatDateToString(MyDateTime)} />
```

Be advised that this works with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update only! More info on this matter [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34846.uwp-compiled-binding-windows-10-anniversary-update.aspx)!

Comment: Hm. Looks like this is the closest I can get. It still feels clunky to have to do this, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Found your question after searching for the answer myself; didn't find much help posted anywhere but did figure it out after some trial and error.

> Function parameter 'provider' is invalid or mismatched

The reason for this that in XAML, a specific overload is being called which is DateTimeProperty.ToString(string, IFormatProvider).

In my case, any value I display is within a User Control so for each I added a CultureInfo dependency property and bound it to common source on my view model.

If C#, add:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Then

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CultureInfoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CultureInfo", typeof(CultureInfo), typeof(XyzReadoutView), new PropertyMetadata(default(CultureInfo)));

    public CultureInfo CultureInfo
    {
        get { return (CultureInfo) GetValue(CultureInfoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CultureInfoProperty, value); }
    }
```

This creates a local instance required for x:Bind, compile errors occur if using a static property.

And XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind MyDateTime.ToString('h:mm tt', CultureInfo)} />
```

Notice the format is surrounded with ' and not ".

Also, this will only update once as the mode for x:Bind has a default of Mode=OneTime; if you want changes on the DateTime or CultureInfo to propagate, the mode must be changed to Mode=OneWay.

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind MyDateTime.ToString('h:mm tt', CultureInfo), Mode=OneWay} />
```

If the format is user changeable, I would create a dependency property for it as well for updates and easy control binding back to a view model but that's just my personal preference.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DateTimeFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DateTimeFormat", typeof(string), typeof(XyzReadoutView), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string DateTimeFormat
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(DateTimeFormatProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateTimeFormatProperty, value); }
    }
```

And XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind MyDateTime.ToString(DateTimeFormat, CultureInfo), Mode=OneWay} />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an IValueConverter to format the text for display. Create a class which inherits from IValueConverter.

```
public class DateFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    // This converts the DateTime object to the string to display.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
        string formatString = parameter as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
        {
            return string.Format(
                new CultureInfo(language), formatString, value);
        }
        // If the format string is null or empty, simply call ToString()
        // on the value.
        return value.ToString();
    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Register it as resource on the Page and then you can specify the converter in the binding

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind MyDateTime, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatConverter}}, ConverterParameter="mm/dd/yyyy"}"/>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter

Comment: I know how to use a converter to accomplish what I'm trying to do. My question is more of a curiosity-question. It seems like there should be a way to specify the signature.

Comment: Avoiding converters is one of the aims of x:Bind.